# Replacement of deprecated PodioContact operation API

Tags: php, podio

What will replace the deprecated [PodioContact](https://developers.podio.com/doc/contacts/create-space-contact-65590) operation in the Podio PHP API if there is any?

```
PodioContact::create( $space_id, $attributes = array() );
```

will it be something like

```
PodioMember::create( $space_id, $attributes = array() );
```

as Space Members are not quite the same.

Comment: You should probably contact Podio directly about this, they may have information on the changes.

Comment: I know, but is the expected way by Podio to contact them about API questions

Answer (score 0):

Podio introduced the new Contact App type - you can read about it in this blog post: http://blog.podio.com/2015/12/09/better-contact-management-podio.

We encourage people to use the contact app instead of workspace contacts. Any newly created organization don't have `Workspace Contacts` feature enabled.

I don't know exactly when we are going to stop support for workspace contacts. It is still a widely used feature so we need to make sure people can safely migrate their data to the new contact app. But if you are implementing new features, just use Contacts app, and create items there :)

Comment: It's a contacts app with a vCard field. :)